# How to dynamically id elements in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am dynamically creating elements with angularjs.  I pass a value number every time I create a new element.  The problem I'm having now is how to get access to this value so that I can concatenate it with the html element ids like such

```
<a class="nav-link active" id="basics-tab"+{{number}} data-toggle="tab" href="#basics"+{{number}} role="tab" aria-controls="basics"+{{number}} aria-selected="true">Basics</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your angular expression should go inside the quotes:

```
<a class="nav-link active" 
  id="basics-tab{{::number}}" 
  data-toggle="tab" 
  href="#basics{{::number}}" 
  role="tab" 
  aria-controls="basics{{::number}}" 
  aria-selected="true">
  Basics
</a>
```

Note: the `::` is a one time binding. If this isn't a dynamically changing list then you should do this to keep the expressions from being evaluated with each digest loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Everything online was either too basic or too advanced.  I am getting one error that is when I use the "::" I get   
"Parser Error: Unexpected token :"  Other than this it appears to be working.

Comment: @Blue, what version of angularJS are you using? make sure you have to semicolons.  I'm not sure when ::binding was introduced, but that could be the problem.